# Laravel unit / model testing

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel

I've been following the Testing Laravel series on Laracasts and am now trying to set up a project according to the TDD and wishfull thinking principles.

Well, I'm at my second test, and I'm confused whether or not it should be a test at all. I have a Customer model that I'd like to test for creation. But I'm unsure how to do this, since `factory(Customer::class)->create();` already creates a Customer.

What would insert/update tests for a Model look like? Are they not neccesary or am I setting up my tests in the wrong way?

At the moment this is my test:

```
/** @test */
public function it_can_add_a_customer()
{
    factory(Customer::class)->create();

    $customers = Customer::all();

    $this->assertCount(1, $customers);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this kind of test are necessary because Models and factory are already tested in the Illuminate package. Still you could test if your fields are present or not, just to be sure that your database have the good structure...

Comment: But what would a test look like to guarantee the store method works? Do I instantiate a controller in the test?

Comment: You mean the store method on your controller?

Comment: Yeah, or does that become a test like `$this->visit('app/customers/create')->type('Name', 'input#name')->press('Save')->seePageIs('app/customers'); `? But if that's the case it would interfere a bit with the Given When Then principle of writing the test, right?

Comment: Well yeah it could be, but it will not be a unit test in this case. I'm not very good at (unit) testing but I guess yeah, you'd have to instantiate your controller, call the store method, put whatever arguments it needs and mock everything to be sure that it all went well. I prefer the "visit" stuff instead of unit testing because it makes more sense to me for a controller

Comment: The difference lies in what you want to test (if I understood correct from the laracasts). I think I'm after an acceptance/integration test here rather than a unit test. The unit test could be something like `function a_customer_has_a_name(){}` that checks if the name can be set or not.

Comment: Yep I understand it the same way as you